# MySQL: Insert or update if row is newer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table A and B, identical, with a timestamp column. I need to update A with B, adding all rows from B that don't exist in A, and updating any rows that already exist with the same pk. That's trivial to do with the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause. However, A might have rows that are actually newer than the same row in B, therefore in those cases where `A.last_modified > B.last_modified` I don't want to do anything.

Is there any simple solution to that?

Comment: Please, show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Write a `SELECT` query that returns all rows in `B` that are either newer than their matching rows in `A`, or don't have a match in `A`. Then use that as the source in `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left join to get the rows you want

```
insert into B
select a.*
from A a
left join B b on a.id = b.id
where b.last_modified < a.last_modified or b.last_modified is null
on duplicate key update ...;
```